# Swapping range of random elements in lists with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have to pick a N number of elements from a list randomly, remove them from the list and add them to another one. My approach so far is something like this:

```
import random

x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
y = []
for v in reversed(list(x)):
  z = x.pop(x.index(random.choice(x)))
  y.append(z)
```

which outputs:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'g']
['b', 'c', 'g']
['c', 'g']
['g']
['e', 'f', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'g']
```

is there a way to write this using list comprehensions? It's going beyond my comprehension.

The original list does not end shuffled, it just has the choosen elements removed.

Comment: you must have an assignment from a teacher who doesnt know python that well ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley *Must* the OP's teacher not know Python very well? Why?

Comment: cause he cant use the tools that already exist and work excellent already...  there are good beginner python assignments, but putting constraints that you cant use language builtins is terrible ... if they dont want them using that feature they should be teaching them in a language that does not have it(ie C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = [x.pop(random.randrange(len(x))) for _ in range(len(x))]
```

If you really want to do exactly this, yes.  There are better ways though.

Comment: This worked, I just didn't understand the underscore, could you explain, please?

Comment: The underscore is just like any other variable name.  By convention, it's used when you have to capture the result of something, but you don't really care about it after that.

Comment: It's important not to use the `_` convention in other languages. I've seen people getting very cross with [tag:javascript] answers that cause underscore.js to be garbage collected, for example.

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is already built into the random module

```
>>> x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
>>> shuffle(x)
>>> x
['b', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'g']
>>>
```

If you don't want to modify x in place just use `shuffle(x[:])`

Comment: I'll edit the question, thing is I don't want to shuffle, I want to randomly pick N number of elements from a list and swap them to another one.

Comment: @joranbeasley Depends on the why, don't you think?

Comment: @JoranBeasley That is premature if you don't know what OP is trying to do, though they should probably clarify.

Comment: @JohnColeman whatever happens OP is still going to end up with a list of "shuffled" elements from the original list...so why re-invent the wheel to achieve the same goal

Comment: @Onilol You can take the first `n` elements of the shuffled list in that case.

Comment: But it seems he wants the first list to be mutated to remove those elements

Comment: `y,x = shuffled_list[:N],shuffled_list[N:]` now x has the elements "removed"

Comment: under the hood random shuffle does just that ... it is clear(since you can go look at the source) ...see http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r32/Lib/random.py (im suprised someone with as much rep as you would not have assumed this already)

Comment: @JoranBeasley You are right about that. The *code* that OP gives has a net result of producing something equivalent to what `random.shuffle()` does, but the use of the word `swap` suggested to me that they wanted to do something with `N` transpositions (which was what was behind my last comment). I suspect that there is some sort of XY problem here with `random.shuffle()` the answer to Y but not X (or vice-versa). Or -- maybe it is just a silly homework problem after all.

Comment: im pretty sure that nails it (the last bit :P)

Comment: ok op has finally clarified some reason why shuffle wont work in general...

Answer (score 1):

As danidee has pointed out, you can use the random module's `shuffle` function to do this:

```
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(x)
print(x)
```

However, if you only want `n` items from the list, use this code:

```
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = 4
y = random.shuffle(x)[0:n]
print(x)
print(y)
```

This might print:

```
[6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
[6, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I'd still have to do something like [z for z in x if z not in y] to remove the items, right ?

Comment: @Onilol You can use the code `alist[:n]` (or `alist[0:n]`) to get items `0` to `n`, and `alist[n:]` (or `alist[n:-1]`) to get items `n` to end-of-list. If you want to keep the order then you would have to do that, but if the order doesn't matter you can just do `x = x[:n]`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing random items one at a time from the middle of a list can be slow (if the list is at all large) since with each removal the remaining items are compacted. It might be better to stich together the non-removed parts. The following function removes the items from a given list which are located at a given list of indices (assumed to be sorted), returns the extracted items, and mutates the list as a side effect:

```
def extract(myList,indices):
    items = myList[:]
    myList.clear()
    extracted = []
    i = 0
    for j in indices:
        myList.extend(items[i:j])
        extracted.append(items[j])
        i = j + 1
    myList.extend(items[i:]) #last fragment, if any
    return extracted
```

Using this, you can write a function that returns `n` items drawn at random from a list, and mutates the original list, keeping the remaining items in the proper order:

```
import random

def drawFrom(myList,n):
    chosen = sorted(random.sample(range(len(myList)),n))
    extracted = extract(myList,chosen)
    random.shuffle(extracted)
    return extracted
```

For example:

```
>>> x = list("abcdefg")
>>> drawFrom(x,3)
['g', 'e', 'b']
>>> x
['a', 'c', 'd', 'f']
```